Vector nodes no longer highlighted in QGIS
I'm using the latest version QGIS 3.34.13. When I have used QGIS before when I hover the mouse over e.g. a line or polygon in a vector layer then a small blue box will appear when I am close to a node.
This functionality seems to have suddenly disappeared and I have searched through all the menus in "Options" but cannot find how to get it back. I have tried on several different vector layers and different projects but the situation is the same in all of them. I have even uninstalled and reinstalled QGIS to no avail.
What could be the problem?

You haven't activated snapping yet.

As mentioned in the comments the snapping needs to be enabled either via Settings>Options>Map Tools>Digitizing or the Snapping Toolbar (right click on the top of qgis menus) the Shortcut is the 'S' button in edit mode.
[QGIS 3.40.0.0 RC used here]

